# Error exporting classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I have taken a code from https://gee-community-catalog.org/projects/S2TSLULC/ for classification purposes. I want to clip the region of interest and output it in GEE. But when I get the export to drive, it gives this error'Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)'. I realized that the error is due to the import of the image collection in the export. Why is it still image collection despite the mosaic on it?
my GEE code is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a81a8f1cf43376b34a676e6d7c8a092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var LC2021= (ee.ImageCollection(esri_lulc10.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31').mosaic().clip(CH_B)).map(remapper));
```

The `mosaic` and `clip` are not well defined. It should be done like this:

```
var LC2021= (ee.ImageCollection(esri_lulc10.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31')).map(remapper)).mosaic().clip(CH_B);
```

This way LC2021 is a single image.

Comment: thank you. in the next step I want reclassify the map into  rangeland and nonRangeland, some wrong with my code. can you check line 146? 'https://code.earthengine.google.com/578d7f49e81cd7dff5471252b52af7b3'

Comment: I will have a look at it. In the meantime, I suggest you should post this as a new question. This way you can elaborate further and more people can see it and find the right answer. You can link this question in your new question for details. 
If my answer did solve the problem, please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark.